# regular expression to validate aadhar NO

Tags: regex, validation

Need help on validating Addhar Card Number with regular expression. It's 12 digit number, in the following format. It can contain 0 to 9 digits.

e.g. `0000 0000 0000`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
^\d{4}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 3):

Aadhaar number validation for Swift 4.0 using the Verhoeff algorithm

```
extension String {

    subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
        return self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: i)]
    }

    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        return String(self[i] as Character)
    }
}

// Convert a Character to an integer.  So '3' becomes interceder 3.

extension Character {
    var integerValue:Int {
        return Int(String(self)) ?? 0
    }
}

class VerhoeffAlgorithm {

    // From https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm
    // based on the "C" implementation

    // The multiplication table
    let verhoeff_d : [[ Int ]] = [
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5],
        [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6],
        [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7],
        [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        [6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2],
        [7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3],
        [8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4],
        [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
        ];

    // The permutation table
    let verhoeff_p : [[Int]] = [
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4],
        [5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2],
        [8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7],
        [9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0],
        [4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1],
        [2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5],
        [7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8],
        ];

    //Validates that an entered number is Verhoeff compliant.  The check digit must be the last one.
    func ValidateVerhoeff(num : String) -> Bool {
        var c : Int = 0;
        let ll : Int = num.count
        for i in 0..<ll {
            c = verhoeff_d[c][verhoeff_p[(i % 8)][(num[ll-i-1]).integerValue]]
        }
        return (c == 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a regex for you but you can use this function to check valid aadhar no.

```
function checkUID(uid) {
    if (uid.length != 12) {
        return false;
    }

    var Verhoeff = {
        "d": [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5],
            [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6],
            [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7],
            [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8],
            [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1],
            [6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2],
            [7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3],
            [8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4],
            [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]],
        "p": [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            [1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4],
            [5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2],
            [8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7],
            [9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0],
            [4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1],
            [2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5],
            [7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8]],
        "j": [0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        "check": function (str) {
            var c = 0;
            str.replace(/\D+/g, "").split("").reverse().join("").replace(/[\d]/g, function (u, i) {
                c = Verhoeff.d[c][Verhoeff.p[i % 8][parseInt(u, 10)]];
            });
            return c;

        },
        "get": function (str) {

            var c = 0;
            str.replace(/\D+/g, "").split("").reverse().join("").replace(/[\d]/g, function (u, i) {
                c = Verhoeff.d[c][Verhoeff.p[(i + 1) % 8][parseInt(u, 10)]];
            });
            return Verhoeff.j[c];
        }
    };

    String.prototype.verhoeffCheck = (function () {
        var d = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5],
            [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6],
            [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7],
            [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8],
            [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1],
            [6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2],
            [7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3],
            [8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4],
            [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]];
        var p = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            [1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4],
            [5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2],
            [8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7],
            [9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0],
            [4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1],
            [2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5],
            [7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8]];

        return function () {
            var c = 0;
            this.replace(/\D+/g, "").split("").reverse().join("").replace(/[\d]/g, function (u, i) {
                c = d[c][p[i % 8][parseInt(u, 10)]];
            });
            return (c === 0);
        };
    })();

    if (Verhoeff['check'](uid) === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function returns true, when its valid aadhar no, else false.
example

console.log("", checkUID("111111111111"));  // false

Comment: this code works.. but not perfect. Example - '999999999999' returns true and '981298798712' returns false

Comment: Did you find any working solution for this problem? @AnilKumar

Answer (score 2):

```
^[0-9]{4}[ -]?[0-9]{4}[ -]?[0-9]{4}$
```

Above regular expression support following format

- 1234 5678 9123
- 123456789123
- 1234-5678-9123

Answer (score 1):

```txt
/(^[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}$)|(^[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}$)|(^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$)/
```

Aadhar Number RegExp Validation

Following numbers are valid:

- `1111-2222-3333` or
- `1111 2222 3333` or
- `111122223333`

Following are invalid:

- `11112222 3333`
- `1111 22223333`
- `1111-22223333`
- `11112222-3333`
- `1111  2222  3333`

Comment: Doesn't validate `1111-2222-3333` and `111122223333`

Answer (score 0):

This regex worked for me to complete basic validation:

```
"^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{11}$"
```

The first part specifies that the first digit is between 2 and 9. The second part specifies that the remaining 11 digits should between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

^(\d{12}|\d{16})$

take the type as long

In Mvc Model,For Eg:

```
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{12}|\d{16})$", ErrorMessage = "enter Integers only")]
    [Display(Name = "Adar ID:")]
    public long sid { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -2):

all the above regex are wrong.
^([0-9]){12}$ is the right one.

Comment: OP's example contains spaces after every four digits, your regex won't match that example